# SSRS - how to return blank as display if your query result is Null using expression

Tags: reporting-services

I am creating a report right now in ssrs that involves two columns from db. The two columns are needed to be combined in the displayed report.

Columns are:
[Column 1] **Price_Low**
[Column 2] **Price_High**

and sample values in both columns is: **0.0000**

1st question how can i combine the 2 column having a dollar sign same this output using SSRS expression:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dim6H.png

2dn question: what if query returns **NULL** how can i display just blank and not, **$ - $**

Here is my sample Exp:
'''=" $" & Fields!Price_Low.Value & " - $" & Fields!Price_High.Value'''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following solution:

```
=IIF(
(Format(Fields!Price_Low.Value, "C4") + " - " + Format(Fields!Price_High.Value,"C4")) = " - ", "",(Format(Fields!Price_Low.Value, "C4") + " - " + Format(Fields!Price_High.Value, "C4"))
)
```

Comment: Thanks @matthew. it works on the report.